# Can not insert id number using postman

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This is the code in nodejs:

```
//Insert an employee
app.post('/employees', (req, res) => {
    let emp = req.body;
    var sql = "SET @EmpID = ?; SET @Name = ?; SET @EmpCode = ?; SET @Salary = ?; \
    CALL EmployeeAddOrEdit(@EmpID,@Name,@EmpCode,@Salary);";
    mysqlConnection.query(sql,[emp.EmpID, emp.Name, emp.EmpCode, emp.Salary],(err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err)
            rows.forEach(element => {
                if (element.constructor == Array)
                    res.send('Inserted employee id : ' + element[0].EmpID);
            });
        else
            console.log(err);
    })
});
```

I don't know if you will be able to see the image.
In the postman it keeps giving me this message:

Inserted employee id : null

Not getting the id number. In mysql workbench created the db with all the data proper settings, had 4 names, the delete process with postman was successful, but can't simply insert the data

Comment: Are you trying to send multiple responses to one request? That won't work. You can't call `res.send('Inserted employee id : ' + element[0].EmpID);` in a loop with more than one iteration. You should call `res.send` exactly once.

Comment: Can you add some more details? What's the actual content of `rows`? You can add a `console.log(rows)`. I would expect `rows` to be an array of rows and `element` to be an array of columns but what is `element[0].EmpID`? `element[0]` should be the value in the first column.

Comment: Why not simply `var sql = "CALL EmployeeAddOrEdit(?,?,?,?);";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return more than one response. So you can't use `res.send` in a loop.

But you can create an array and add all the ids to the array and present them in the response.

```
//Insert an employee
app.post('/employees', (req, res) => {
    let emp = req.body;
    var sql = "SET @EmpID = ?; SET @Name = ?; SET @EmpCode = ?; SET @Salary = ?; \
    CALL EmployeeAddOrEdit(@EmpID,@Name,@EmpCode,@Salary);";
    const container = []; //Create an empty array

    mysqlConnection.query(sql, [emp.EmpID, emp.Name, emp.EmpCode, emp.Salary], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err) {
            rows.forEach(element => {
                if (element.constructor == Array)
                    container.push(row.insertedId); //Push the ids to the array
            });
            res.send('Inserted employee ids : ' + container.join());
        }

        else
            console.log(err);
    })
});
```